# How to fix wrong count on joined table in sql

Tags: sql, count, aggregate

I am encountering a problem when counting files when I join this table to another. Either I am getting a higher or lower than what it should be.

Using this simple query, I am able to get the right count:

```
select count(files.id)
from files
where files.OpeningDate between '2015-11-01' and '2015-11-30'
  and files.CustomerID = 3258
```

Result: 420

When I am trying to integrate it in a more complex query:

```
SELECT  
    FORMAT(files.OpeningDate, 'yyyy-MM') as OpeningDateFormatted,
    SUM(CASE WHEN transactiontypeid IN (2, 5) THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS AdjustmentSum,
    SUM(CASE WHEN transactionTypeID = 1 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS InterestSum,
    SUM(CASE WHEN transactionTypeID IN (8, 17, 25, 18) THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS CreditSum,
    SUM(CASE WHEN transactionTypeID IN (10, 7, 12, 14, 11, 21) THEN amount ELSE 0 end) AS PaymentSum,
    COUNT(DISTINCT(files.id)) AS count1,
    COUNT((files.id)) AS count2
FROM 
    files
LEFT JOIN 
    filestransactions ON files.id = filestransactions.exid
WHERE 
    FilesTransactions.TransactionDate BETWEEN '2015-10-01' AND '2019-09-30' 
    AND ExID IN (SELECT id 
                 FROM files 
                 WHERE files.OpeningDate BETWEEN '2015-10-01' AND '2019-09-30' 
                   AND files.CustomerID = 3258)
GROUP BY 
    FORMAT(files.OpeningDate, 'yyyy-MM')
ORDER BY
    OpeningDateFormatted
```

Count1: 296, Count2: 481 for 2015-11

I have tried different combinations of left/right/inner join with and without distinct, I have also tried to use a subquery, but I can't get the right count which is 420.

Can I get some advises to get on the right track?

Comment: 2 queries with different where criteria and you're surprised they return different counts?  Your first query says there are 420 files.id `where files.OpeningDate between '2015-11-01' and '2015-11-30' and files.CustomerID = 3258`.  Your second query says there are 481 files.id of which 125 are duplicates `where files.OpeningDate between '2015-11-01' and '2015-11-30' and files.CustomerID = 3258` **and a bunch of other stuff, some of which eliminates some files.id and some of which duplicates some files.id**

Comment: What is the cardinality between 2 tables ?

Comment: `File can have 0..* FilesTransactions`

`FilesTransactions belongs to 1..1 file`